# 90's anime-like musical video: in a weapon factory, a guy growing bigger sheds skin revealing another layer of skin

Tags: anime, music-identification, music-video

I saw it in the 90's. It was a musical video, it looked like hand-drawn anime, stylistically close to [*Neo Tokyo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo_Tokyo_(film)) (1987). I don't remember the music or lyrics at all.

In the clip, something happened on some kind of weapon factory. A guy took weird-looking gun form the conveyor belt and started to get bigger, Hulk-style. Only his skin was *bursting* and underneath was *another layer of skin*.

I doubt that video was drawn specially for the clip and would be glad to find out the source material!

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Answer (score 7):

There's a chance you could be remembering Wamdue Project's House track *King of my Castle*, released 1999.

The video is composed of cuts from the anime [*Ghost in the Shell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell_(1995_film)) (released 1995), a futuristic movie set in Tokyo (hence your Neotokyo reference), and contains this "skin underneath skin" shot (I picked the least NSFW bit):

[image: woman floating in water tank with her skin flaking off]

I couldn't find references to the conveyor belt or the Hulk-style transformation, but there *are* many weapons and it's been many years, so memory might have become mixed up.

Comment: No, that's not it, sorry.